# output all images(png) filenames in a hard drive (not just dir) Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line

I know that to output all images (.png) in a single folder is

`dir *.png`

but I can't figure out how to check my whole hardrive (all folders and subfolders) for .png files.

Thank you.

Comment: Add the **/S** switch to your dir command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I can't figure out how to check my whole hardrive for .png files.

You need to use the `/s` (include all subfolders) option.

You might also want to consider using `/b` (Bare format (no heading, file sizes or summary)) as well.

**Examples**

To search the whole of drive C:

```
cd /d c:\
dir /s /b *.png
```

To search the whole of drive C, and save the output:

```
cd /d c:\
dir /s /b *.png > files.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [cd](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) - Change Directory - Select a Folder (and drive)
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.